# Remote Desktop Client connection - can connect via cellphone, cannot via landline + router ASUS + public, static IP

Tags: networking, router, remote-desktop, internet, diagnostic

I want to connect from home to office Windows Server using the [Remote Desktop Connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services) (Microsoft) [client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Client_software). The server's RDP port is non standard one - my admin claims that opening a standard port of 3389 is insecure.

1. When I connect my laptop to the network using my cellphone it works like charm - I connect successfully and it works.
2. At home I have landline with public, static IP plus ASUS Wireless Router. Unfortunately bdzionk - each time I get timeout.

I am trying to pinpoint the problem and tried to connect to a friends workstation using standard port of 3389 and I was able to connect.

Apparently my home router or a network provider do block RDP connections on non-standard ports (other services work as expected).

How to better diagnose and solve the problem?
How to determine whether there is a problem with Asus router or my network provider?

Comment: Enable upnp on your router to see if this changes anything. Also try port forwarding the relevant ports.

Comment: Does port forwarding has anything to do with connecting as client? I do not have anything in router logs. UPnP and port forwarding would be relevant if I would be setting up a server. Any relevance to client connection?

Comment: @PawelDebski - Port Forwarding is only required to open incoming traffic on a port to a specific machine on **your** network.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. Still seeking solution.